# Traverse Object and build Tree Lineage

Tags: javascript, iteration, tree-traversal

Json Object :

```
var json = {
    "Tree": [{
        "Title": "Condition",
        "Attr": {
            "Id": 2258,
            "Zone": null
        },
        "Children": [{
            "Title": "General Wellness",
            "Attr": {
                "Id": 2315,
                "Zone": null
            },
            "Children": [{
                "Title": "Family Health",
                "Attr": {
                    "Id": 2262,
                    "Zone": null
                },
                "Children": []
            }, {
                "Title": "Healthy Home",
                "Attr": {
                    "Id": 2316,
                    "Zone": null
                },
                "Children": []
            }, {
                "Title": "Vitamins",
                "Attr": {
                    "Id": 2317,
                    "Zone": null
                },
                "Children": []
            }, {
                "Title": "Recipes",
                "Attr": {
                    "Id": 2318,
                    "Zone": null
                },
                "Children": []
            }, {
                "Title": "Caregiving",
                "Attr": {
                    "Id": 2325,
                    "Zone": null
                },
                "Children": []
            }, {
                "Title": "Healthy Eating",
                "Attr": {
                    "Id": 2346,
                    "Zone": null
                },
                "Children": []
            }, {
                "Title": "Travel Health",
                "Attr": {
                    "Id": 2347,
                    "Zone": null
                },
                "Children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I am able to traverse the tree however I am unable to build a tree structure for example if I wanted to look for "Recipes" it should return me the result as :

Condition > General Wellness > Recipes

UPDATE :

Traversing is done via :

```
function process(key,value) {
    alert(key + " : "+value);
}

function traverse(o,func) {
    for (var i in o) {
        func.apply(this,[i,o[i]]);  
        if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {            
            traverse(o[i],func);
        }
    }
}

traverse(json,process);
```

Comment: JSON is invalid
http://jsonlint.com/ validate here.

Comment: @depperm added traversal logic

Comment: @Rhea corrected Json

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an iterative, as you already had, approach with a defined exit if found and a repeated calling if not found. The path is created if the target is found.

Bonus: The `getPath` returns the success of the search.

```js
function getPath(array, target, path) {
    return array.some(function (a) {
        if (a.Title === target) {
            return path.unshift(a.Title);
        } else if (Array.isArray(a.Children)) {
            return getPath(a.Children, target, path) && path.unshift(a.Title);
        }
    });
}

var data = {
        "Tree": [{
            "Title": "Condition",
            "Attr": {
                "Id": 2258,
                "Zone": null
            },
            "Children": [{
                "Title": "General Wellness",
                "Attr": {
                    "Id": 2315,
                    "Zone": null
                },
                "Children": [{
                    "Title": "Family Health",
                    "Attr": {
                        "Id": 2262,
                        "Zone": null
                    },
                    "Children": []
                }, {
                    "Title": "Healthy Home",
                    "Attr": {
                        "Id": 2316,
                        "Zone": null
                    },
                    "Children": []
                }, {
                    "Title": "Vitamins",
                    "Attr": {
                        "Id": 2317,
                        "Zone": null
                    },
                    "Children": []
                }, {
                    "Title": "Recipes",
                    "Attr": {
                        "Id": 2318,
                        "Zone": null
                    },
                    "Children": []
                }, {
                    "Title": "Caregiving",
                    "Attr": {
                        "Id": 2325,
                        "Zone": null
                    },
                    "Children": []
                }, {
                    "Title": "Healthy Eating",
                    "Attr": {
                        "Id": 2346,
                        "Zone": null
                    },
                    "Children": []
                }, {
                    "Title": "Travel Health",
                    "Attr": {
                        "Id": 2347,
                        "Zone": null
                    },
                    "Children": []
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            Title: 'abc',
            Children: [{
                Title: 'def',
                Children: [{
                    Title: 'ghi'
                }]
            }, {
                Title: 'jkl',
                Children: [{
                    Title: 'mno'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    path = [];
document.write(getPath(data.Tree, 'Recipes', path) + ': ' + path.join(' &gt; ') + '<br>');
path = [];
document.write(getPath(data.Tree, 'ghi', path) + ': ' + path.join(' &gt; ') + '<br>');
path = [];
document.write(getPath(data.Tree, 'nonsense', path) + ': ' + path.join(' &gt; ') + '<br>');
```